# Placement of ne and pas to mean “What have you not done?”

Tags: grammaire, négation, questions

I've been having a hard time translating “What have you not done” in French, I know how to say “What have you done”.

> Qu'as fait tu ?

But I don't know how to say “What have you not done” without “qu'est-ce que”.

Do you say:

> Que n'as fait tu pas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

“Qu'as fait tu ?” is not correct. According to [francaisfacile.com](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-64995.php) (emphasis mine), in questions:

> 1. On conjugue un verbe impérativement en plaçant le pronom sujet
>      a) après le verbe aux temps simples et
>      b) **après l'auxiliaire aux temps composés**.

So the correct phrasing is

> Qu'as-tu fait ?

And the negation:

> Que n'as-tu pas fait ?

Comment: « On conjugue un verbe **impérativement** en […] » : Il me semble que le mot en gras doit être *interrogativement*.

Comment: "impérativement" ne se réfère pas ici au mode impératif, mais signifie "obligatoirement".

Answer (score 6):

> - Qu'as-tu fait ?
> - Que n'as-tu pas fait ?

*Que n'as-tu pas fait ?* est une formule soutenue,
L'usage habituel (et correct) : *Qu'est-ce que tu n'as pas fait ?*